# I am getting this error while making a project in expo using this command-> expo init project-name

Tags: expo

? Choose a template: blank
[16:22:15] Extracting project files...
Process exited with non-zero code: 2
ERROR: Unexpected end of data : blank-30.1.0.tar

Process exited with non-zero code: 2
[16:22:17] zlib: unexpected end of file
[16:22:17] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today but I found the answer.

The file `blank-30.1.0.tar` was not downloaded correctly. Trying to clear the `npm` cache won't help, because expo has its own cache.

Use this command to clear the expo cache on Windows or on Linux:

```
rm -fr ~/.expo/starter-app-cache
```

or try to find it on macOS under `~\.exponent\starter-app-cache\`

Comment: ??how to use that command . Is it inside project directory or

Comment: You can manually delete files from expo c:/users/$userName/.expo in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Delete .expo folder 
Run

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
npm install -g expo-cli@latest
expo init <project-name>
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

I have manually deleted my file from .expo folder. As my system not recognize rm -fr command.

You can find cache file in c:/users/$userName/.expo in windows.